# Подключение Retrofit к Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit

Подключаю к проекту библиотеку `Retrofit`, подключил

```
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

в `Gradle`, в активити добавил

```
import retrofit.client.Response;
import retrofit.http.GET;
```

но все равно не видит класс `Retrofit` на пример

```
Retrofit retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
```

В чем может быть ошибка? И правильно ли я подключаю?

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hp.apps"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner         
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
```

Comment: Можно полный код файла `build.gradle` в котором прописывали зависимости

Comment: Добавил код в build.gradle

Comment: Включи в настройках автоимпорт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы же Retrofit 2 подключаете, его и импортируйте в коде

```
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
```